# PHPMailer, attachment settings can't access file (csv fiile)

Tags: php, csv, phpmailer

I'm running a PHP script that runs a sequence of SQL queries, writes the results to CSV, and saves it. It also mails the report to a recipient.

The CSV portion of the code works perfectly, and the PHPMailer portion sends the test email with no problem. However, when I un-comment the attachment portion of PHPMailer and run the script it says "File could not be accessed". When I replace the comment, it writes the file and sends the test email again just fine.

The line in question, which I comment/uncomment accordingly, is: `$mail->addAttachment($fp);`

So, the two pieces are working, but this being my first time using PHPMailer, I'm not sure the best way to go about fixing this. As far as I can tell, I'm using the `addAttachment` code properly and I'm closing the CSV at the very end.

Any help is much appreciated.

The script:

```
                if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
            $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
            $headers = array();
            while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
                $headers[] = $fieldinfo->name;
            }
            $fp = fopen('dailyReportTestPHP.csv', 'w');
            if ($fp && $result) {
                fputcsv($fp, $headers);
                while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
                }

            }


            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $address = "hnorman@jacksonfurnind.com";

            try{
            $mail->setFrom("hnorman@jacksonfurnind.com");
            $mail->addAddress($address);
            $mail->addAttachment($fp);
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject    = "Test";
            $mail->Body       = "Test";
            $mail->Send();
            echo 'message sent';

            } catch (Exception $e){
                echo 'message failed';
                echo 'mail error:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }

            fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `$fp` is an open file handle; PHPMailer is expecting a string containing the path to the file to be passed to `addAttachment()`. So, move the `fclose` call to before you create the PHPMailer instance, and then do this:

```
$mail->addAttachment('dailyReportTestPHP.csv');
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, I totally overlooked the fact that it couldn't use that handle. Thanks!